# How to filter out objects if two keys are duplicate

Tags: javascript

```
const obj  = 
[
       {
          "id":"1",
          "name":"a",
          "email":"abc@gmail.com",
          "expiryType":"premium"
        },
        {
          "id":"2",
          "name":"b",
          "email":"abc@gmail.com",
          "expiryType":"gold"
        },
        {
          "id":"3",
          "name":"b",
          "email":"test@gmail.com",
          "expiryType":"premium"
        },
    ]
```

can somebody please help me how to filter out objects where email is same but i want to keep the one with expiry Type is premium ? How to achieve this using Javascript

Expected output would be

```
const obj  = 
[
       {
          "id":"1",
          "name":"a",
          "email":"abc@gmail.com",
          "expiryType":"premium"
        },
        {
          "id":"3",
          "name":"b",
          "email":"test@gmail.com",
          "expiryType":"premium"
        },
    ]
```

Comment: You mean if two values are duplicated not keys?

Comment: sorry yes values

Comment: @DhaivatParikh : please, append expected output and your current attempt

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out whole object based on unique key you want as below.

```
const obj  = 
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "gold"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    }
]

function arrayUnique(arr, uniqueKey) {
  const flagList = []
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    if (flagList.findIndex(flagItem => flagItem[uniqueKey] === item[uniqueKey]) === -1) {
      flagList.push(item)
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

**Method Calling....**

```
let newObj = arrayUnique(obj,'email')
```

Output:

```
newObj = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to filter out the premium only between the objects that have the same value for email

Comment: Do you mean that, you want to filter data based on premium expiryType & same emails ?
Please add expected output in your question. So I will update my answer based on that.

Comment: yes. please see the updated question,  i have added the expected output. Basically i want all customer but remove the expiry type = premium where emails are exact sam. @Chintan thanks a lot for the help man.

Comment: Actually If you will try my answer now.... You will get exactly same answer that you want. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: You can pass any key out of that object...that based no which you want to filter similar objects. & To get expected output....that is >>  [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    }
]
Just pass email

Comment: const obj  = 
[
    
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "gold"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "x"
    }
]

try your code with this input

Comment: It will return >>>> [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "x"
    }
]

Comment: nope it returns ===> const obj = [ { "id": "2", "name": "b", "email": "abc@gmail.com", "expiryType": "gold" }, 

{ "id": "3", "name": "b", "email": "test@gmail.com", "expiryType": "x" } ];

which is not desired output

Comment: my point is it return the random from the duplicates within array of objects. to be specific it returns the one that is on top (lower index in array). try this input const obj  = 
[ {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "gold"
    },
     {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
];

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the latest year's entry, you can keep a Map of the email addresses and years you've seen. See comments:

```
// The new list
const filtered = [];
// Known emails
const known = new Map();
// Loop through...
for (const entry of obj) {
    // Get this email and expiry
    const {email, expiryYear} = entry;
    // Get the previous info if any
    const previous = known.get(email);
    if (previous) {
        // If the previous one is older than this one,
        // replace it with this one
        if (previous.expiryYear < expiryYear) {
            filtered[previous.index] = entry;
        }
    } else {
        // Add this to the known list and the filtered array
        known.set(email, {
            index: filtered.length,
            expiryYear
        });
        filtered.push(entry);
    }
}
```

```js
const obj  = [
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"a",
      "email":"abc@gmail.com",
      "expiryYear":"2020"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"a",
      "email":"abc@gmail.com",
      "expiryYear":"2019"
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"b",
      "email":"test@gmail.com",
      "expiryYear":"2020"
    },
];

// The new list
const filtered = [];
// Known emails
const known = new Map();
// Loop through...
for (const entry of obj) {
    // Get this email and expiry
    const {email, expiryYear} = entry;
    // Get the previous info if any
    const previous = known.get(email);
    if (previous) {
        // If the previous one is older than this one,
        // replace it with this one
        if (previous.expiryYear < expiryYear) {
            filtered[previous.index] = entry;
        }
    } else {
        // Add this to the known list and the filtered array
        known.set(email, {
            index: filtered.length,
            expiryYear
        });
        filtered.push(entry);
    }
}

console.log(filtered);
```

This has the advantage of not constantly re-scanning the new list for known entries.

Comment: @t-j-crowder can you please update code according to the updated question?

Comment: @DhaivatParikh - Just change `expiryYear` to `expiryType` throughout, and change the condition for replacing from `if (previous.expiryYear < expiryYear)` to `if (expiryType === "premium")`.

Comment: nope it doesnt work its not getting the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with 2 loops. Maybe not the fastes but the simplest:

```
function deleteDouble(array, objectKey) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
          if (i == j) {
            continue;
          }
          if (array[i][objectKey] == array[j][objectKey]) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return array;
    }

deleteDouble(obj, "email");
```

Comment: i dont get the correct out put if the input is 



const obj  = 
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "premium"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "b",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "expiryType": "gold"
    }
];